# Cannot remove docker application and container in docker desktop

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-app

This `nodedocker` docker application has been stuck on my docker desktop for a while now. I've tried deleting it numerous times to no avail. Running `docker ps` shows no running container. I even tried deleting the container `nodedocker_database_1`, but the results the same. Running `docker compose down -v` tears down all other containers except for this one. Any sort of lead would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the Docker Desktop app GUI to remove all the individual containers, the application should also be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove with terminal using this commands:

- To list all containers with id and other infos

  ***docker ps -a***

to remove the container:

```
docker rm "idOfContainer" without ""
```

Comment: I use an additional parameter: -f, --force Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL). docker rm -f "idOfContainer"

Answer (score 1):

Usually closing and restarting docker desktop fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

don't try to delete the container group. If you delete the containers under the group one by one, your problem will be solved. The group is already deleted automatically.